# How to start .bat files which i just collected out of a folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

When i find `.bat` files with `get-childitems` from a specific folder like this :

```
$bats = Get-ChildItem "C:\Projects\PSScripts\batfiles"

foreach ($bat in $bats) 
{
  start-process  
}
```

how do i make them run ? start-process didn't work

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Projects\PSScripts\batfiles' -Filter '*.bat' | % {
  & $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how my suggestion is not working with `Get-ChildItem`. Please elaborate.

Comment: my fault of course. sorry :) i misread something 2 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
get-childitem . | foreach-object { start-process -filepath $_ }
```

Obviously instead of dot use your directory path.

First you get all your files with get-childitem and then you pass the result using pipeline into foreach object. $_ represents variable in the current iteration.

If you want to use your script block, it should be like this:

```
$bats = Get-ChildItem "C:\Projects\PSScripts\batfiles"

foreach ($bat in $bats) 
{
  start-process -filepath $bat
}
```

Comment: i guess i need more practice. i can't make it run like this :(